# Label Masking in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, labeling, clip, arcgis-pro

The data frame "Clip to Shape" feature, to hide both symbols and labels outside of a specified shape, seems to be gone from ArcGIS Pro.

I'm able to use Masking (Feature Layer->Appearance->Drawing->Masking) to get the same results for the symbols, but the labels continue to be generated everywhere.

Is there any way that will mask labels outside of a shape without having to actually clip the data?

Comment: I found a post on the GeoNet Site: https://community.esri.com/ideas/12615-clip-map-to-shape-in-arcgis-pro, basically using the "Reshape Tool" accomplishes this.

Comment: That is the exact problem that I'm having, thanks for finding that post. I hope it gets the attention of the developers.

Answer (score 1):

Per @Keagan Allan and to provide a response for the time being. It appears that this feature is yet to be available in ArcGIS Pro. In ArcMap, you could use the "Reshape Tool"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Masking Layers by Layer]

Two-three years later: Masking available for layers and labels.

Comment: Are you saying it is now possible to mask labels? The dropdown you're showing is listing layers and still doesn't appear to affect labels, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: yes this answer is not correct for the question. Masking works for hiding the features but not the labels.